# Error: wrong model type for regression, using train() in R

Tags: r, regression, classification, linear-regression, prediction

Does anyone knows why model1 is working but model2, model3, and model4 give this error:

```
Error: wrong model type for regression
```

```
model1 <- lda(website_fakeness~ .,data=dfn)



model2 <- train(x= dfn, y= as.factor(dfn$website_fakeness), method="lda")

model3 <- train(dfn$website_fakeness~.,data=dfn,  method="lda")

model4 <- train(website_fakeness~.,data=dfn,  method="lda")
```

website_fakeness is my dependent variable including 0 or 1 values.

I don't have such an issue with other prediction models using them in train() such as "svm", "knn", "mlp", "nb" ,...  but train() does not work with  "lda", "qda", "gam".

what could be wrong?

Comment: Try `model3 <- train(website_fakeness~.,data=dfn,  method="lda")`

Comment: I have tried. I got the same error

Comment: Did you convert the variable to factor before using the above? `dfn$website_fakeness <- factor(dfn$website_fakeness)`

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That should include what packages you're using, such as where `train` and `lda` come from and what exactly your goal is. Without any data or output, it's hard to know what's going on, so it's hard to know how to help